# Wordpress Php print / echo input results from previous page

Tags: php, wordpress, printing, input, echo

I am trying to create a php function in wordpress where a user answers a question on one page and then prints their answer on the next page after they hit submit.

The data does not need to be collected in a database just printed so it shows what the user typed.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have any code to show or a demo ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a form to do this. Create HTML form with an input for the answer that gets submitted to a php file on submit:

```
<form action="print.php" method="POST">
     <input type="text" name="user_answer" />
     <input type="submit" value="answer question!" />
</form>
```

Then have a PHP file (called print.php in this example);

```
$answer = $_POST['user_answer'];
echo $answer;
```